# timer method wont add textfield to sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

When i press keyboard down button the textfield is added to sprite but not through timer event call. Why is that ?

```
package
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {

        public function Test()
        {
            var timer:Timer = new Timer(3);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTime);
            timer.start();

        }

        function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

            //          graphics.lineStyle(10,Math.random() * 10000, 10);
            //          graphics.drawCircle(100, 100, 80);  

            var txtFld:TextField = new TextField();

            txtFld.x = 200;
            txtFld.y = 200;
            txtFld.width = 25;
            txtFld.height = 15;
            txtFld.text = "90";         

            addChild(txtFld);
        }



        function onTime(event:Timer):void {


            var txtFld:TextField = new TextField();

            txtFld.x = 100;
            txtFld.y = 100;
            txtFld.width = 25;
            txtFld.height = 15;
            txtFld.text = "80";     

            addChild(txtFld);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the timer event handler, you've cast the incoming event object as `Timer`, not `TimerEvent`.  This causes Flash player to throw an error.

Also, this code will continue to add TextFields because the Timer is looping and calling this function on every loop.

```
function onTime(event:TimerEvent):void {
    //stop the timer
    evt.target.stop();

    var txtFld:TextField = new TextField();

    txtFld.x = 100;
    txtFld.y = 100;
    txtFld.width = 25;
    txtFld.height = 15;
    txtFld.text = "80";     

    addChild(txtFld);
}
```